# FreeBSD create user without utility?

Tags: freebsd, users, passwd

I have a user that I created via the `pw` utility on FreeBSD. The full command I used was:

```
pw add user example -s /usr/local/scripts/example.sh -w none
```

The user can login as example without requiring a password which will run the example script. Once the script is done running the user will be automatically logged out.

I want to duplicate this user, but  I'm looking into a way of doing it without requiring a utility. For example, I looked into modifying the `/etc/passwd` file, but it doesn't look like that worked. The reason I say it didn't work is because it prompts me for a password and of course I don't have one for this user I tried to add.

Is what I'm after possible? Do I absolutely have to use utilities such as `pw`?

Just a quick edit. Perhaps the only thing I'm missing is setting the user to not require a password. My edit of `/etc/passwd` could be correct, and all I require would be to somehow set this new user to not require a password.

Comment: what do you mean with duplicate? Also you cannot only edit the /etc/passwd, because there are more file related to a user

Comment: @demonking: By duplicate, I mean create an identical user, besides the username. The user I created is a simple user that just runs a script upon login. No password. What other files do I need to edit besides the `/etc/passwd` file? That's essentially what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're editing the wrong file, and you're not actually modifying the system accounts database, which is why you aren't seeing any modifications.

This is not Linux.  The master *source file* for the accounts database is `/etc/master.passwd`.  `/etc/passwd` is a Version 7 Unix compatibility file, a subordinate file generated from the source.  The actual system accounts database that is consulted by applications wanting to look stuff up is a pair of Berkeley DB files, also generated from the source file by `pwd_mkdb`.

`vipw` runs `pwd_mkdb` automatically.  If you hand-edit `/etc/master.passwd`, you must (carefully) run `pwd_mkdb` yourself.

If you hand-edit `/etc/passwd` your changes will be lost the next time that `pwd_mkdb` gets run and will not be seen by applications anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do; hand modify master.passwd and run pwd_mkdb. This works perfectly and answers the original question. I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit the [passwd(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd&sektion=5) file, use [vipw(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vipw). The file `/etc/passwd` is just a shadow file.

To set the password to empty, simply remove the second parameter (between two `:` characters). For example, if `root` had an empty password, `vipw` would show you something like this:

```
  root::0:0::0:0:Charlie &:/root:/bin/csh
```

The *real* username and password database is located in /etc/pwd.db. See [pwd_mkdb(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pwd_mkdb) for more details.

Comment: I'm looking for a way of editing without using a utility. vipw will add a user, but I'm looking for a way without using a utility. I had a quick go using vipw. I notice that it modifies the `/etc/passwd` file and the `/etc/master.passwd` file. If I delete the user from these files manually, I can still login with the user I created. So it seems that vipw modifies more than just those 2 files.

Comment: @quickblueblur The other file is `/etc/pwd.db`. Which is the *real* username and password database.

Comment: Thank you! That was handy information. If I hand edit the `/etc/passwd` file and the `/etc/master.passwd` file and run the following command `pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd` I am able to create the user and login successfully. If you would like to edit your answer to include the information about `/etc/pwd.db` I can accept the answer.